# Does ASUS RT-N66U still route traffic to Internet if VPN drops?

Tags: router, vpn, openvpn

ASUS RT-N66U is one of the most popular routers to put Tomato on.  However, some people choose to use the stock firmware.

Using the stock firmware, with a VPN client configured, will the ASUS RT-N66U still route traffic through to the Internet if the VPN connection gets interrupted?  If not, how do you configure this behavior?

Comment: If it didn't, how would you ever get the VPN back?

Comment: that's a good point.  how do the kill-switch capabilities work?  it's only allowed to try to reconnect to the vpn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be typical behaviour for almost any system with a VPN - the VPN software needs to be able to connect to the wider Internet to set up the VPN, or reset it when it drops.

Comment: Are you saying the RT-N66U will not connect out to the WAN if the VPN client specified fails?

Comment: No, I'm saying the opposite.  The router will send traffic onto the Internet if the VPN is down.

Comment: ah.  i accidentally proved your theory true today.  i used to have tomato installed on it, which had killswitch capabilities.  thx for the info.